# How to get "true url" of google search results in javascript

Tags: javascript, url, google-search

Whenever you click on a Google link, it redirects you through their website like this:

> `https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHI&ei=y8mSVJb3HYqlNqvBgIgM&usg=AFQjCNEWA_V3hjoVAu_W7mu3fbN6Q4n0Lw&sig2=dDRuO4YH9VIDXgQoZJH4tQ&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY`

Is there any way to get the actual URL (`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HI`) using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var googleUrl = "...";
var start = googleUrl.indexOf("&url=") + 5;
var end = googleUrl.indexOf("&", start)
var encodedUrl = googleUrl.substring(start, end);
//var encodedUrl = googleUrl.substr(start, end - start); //OK too
var url = decodeURIComponent(encodedUrl); //this what you want
```

It's important to extract the encoded url first and then decode it because the url itself may contain query parameters. Imagine what happens if they also conflict with those used by google.

Thanks, @James Donnelly. I ommited that `unescape` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
var a = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHI&ei=y8mSVJb3HYqlNqvBgIgM&usg=AFQjCNEWA_V3hjoVAu_W7mu3fbN6Q4n0Lw&sig2=dDRuO4YH9VIDXgQoZJH4tQ&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY";

var b = decodeURIComponent(a);
var p1 = b.indexOf("&url");
var p2 = b.indexOf("&ei");
var res = b.substring(p1+5, p2);

alert(res);
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fx23/4/)

Comment: But you are assuming that "ei" is after of "url", and they can be in other order.

Comment: @sergiomse: Thanks for pointing out the issue. Do you have any link  to support this. It would be pretty useful.

Comment: @sergiomse: http://www.t75.org/2012/06/deconstructing-googles-url-search-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

The direct way to do this is with [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(url)

params.get('url') // "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HI"
```

This has been supported by virtually all browsers (and Node.js) since around [2016](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams), with the notable exception of IE, for which you'll need a [polyfill](https://github.com/search?q=URLSearchParams+polyfill&s=stars).